# remapping shift key and bash script startup problem

Tags: bash, keyboard-layout, input-devices

My keyboard both shift key malfunctioned, my OS is Ubuntu 13.04. So I am using one of the control key as shift key. I did this using `xkeycaps` tool, and that's working fine and I need to do this command from terminal every time I login. xkeycaps auto-create a script `xmod.sh` of remapping keyboard keys. I do this command after startup:

```
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap-`uname -n`
```

So, I write a bash command at `init.d` and also sets up permission to startup at login. Though its not working. I had to manually enter the command in terminal all the time.

My bash script is there:

```
sudo cat /etc/init.d/xmod.sh
```

Permission to startup:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/xmod.sh
```

Updating `init.d`:

```
sudo update-rc.d xmod.sh defaults
```

and `xmod.sh` contains:

```
#!bin/bash
xmodmap ~/.xmodmap-`uname -n`
```

Please experts tell me what am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that is ok to use that script in `init.d`. Like this the script will run at boot time, before your login. At that time, `~` is not set.

I think that the best way to get `` xmodmap ~/.xmodmap-`uname -n` `` command to run after your login is to create a file called **`.xinitrc`** in your home directory (`~`), containing the following line:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap-`uname -n`
```

A relogin will be probably necessary.